# How to resolve 403 forbidden error i am facing when testing batch endpoint from ML Studio with Bearer token obtained using Azure active directory

Tags: azure, authentication, batch-processing, access-token, endpoint

In this image u can see that i have used scope (audience) as https://ml.azure.com/.default because the batch endpoint which I'm going to test is obtained from Azure ML studio and i have give all the secrets, id which is obtained from azure active directory authentication(AAD) and finally i got the bearer token and but when passing bearer token to batch endpoint it is giving 403 forbidden error  (BY_POLICY )issue(2nd image) . please explain what is this BY_POLICY issue and how to resolve it ?[1st_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vh99g.png)
[2nd image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmTW7.png)

i got the bearer token from postman and but when passing bearer token to batch endpoint it is giving BY_POLICY issue . please explain what is this BY_POLICY issue and how to resolve it ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have certain permissions on the Azure ML instance to be able to query the batch endpoint, as described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-authenticate-batch-endpoint?view=azureml-api-2&tabs=cli#how-authorization-works).
Make sure that the identity you are using does have roles granting these permissions.

Comment: In the documentation I see that 6 permissions are required. I granted the "AzureML Compute Operator" role on the workspace and expected that this covers the 6 permissions but it still does not work.